# ContextMenu item not visible in web word

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm doing a Word add-in using office.js, and have successfully registered a ContextMenu item and a callback function.

In my locally installed Word application, the item shows up as expected when right-clicking inside a document.

In the browser based word however, it only shows up when I right click a selected piece of text.

Is this a bug?

**manifest.xml**

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
    <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuText">
        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button1Id1">
            <Label resid="ContextMenuItem.Label" />
            <Supertip>
                <Title resid="ContextMenuItem.Label"/>
                <Description resid="ContextMenuItem.Tooltip"/>
            </Supertip>
            <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
            </Icon>
            <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>doStuff</FunctionName>
            </Action>
        </Control>
    </OfficeMenu>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

**callback function**

```
function doStuff(event) {
   console.log("Got invoked!");
   event.completed();
}
```